# laravel where clause value and column name

Tags: mysql, laravel

How can i do these in laravel query where clause?

```
select * from table_samples where 1 = id 
// basically i can do like where id = 1

select * from table_samples where 1000 > rate
 // basically i can do like where rate < 1000

select * from table_samples where 'bogart' = name
 // basically i can do like where name = "bogart"
```

My point is if you interchange the `column` and `value` its working on mysql, but if i do this in laravel where clause it doesn't work?

Something like

```
TableSample::where('1','id')->first();
TableSample::where('1000','>','rate')->first();
TableSample::where('bogart','name')->first();
// throws an error undefined column name 1, 100, and bogart.

// I know laravel . These are the correct query
TableSample::where('id','1')->first();
TableSample::where('rate','<','1000')->first();
TableSample::where('name','bogart')->first();
```

Is there any where clauses functions in laravel that can accept or determine if you try to interchange the `value` and `column`?

Comment: You can extend the query builder and then write your code like `TableSample::tsrif()->erehw(1, 'di');` But why would someone want to do that?

Comment: No. its just a basic example to emphasize what i want to do in a complex query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You yan use `DB::raw()` for this.

```
TableSample::whereRaw('? = id', [1])->first();
```

Just make sure you use parameter substitution like above to prevent creating sql injection vulnerabilities.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

> The `whereRaw` and `orWhereRaw` methods can be used to inject a raw where clause into your query

```
TableSample::whereRaw('1 = id')->first();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-methods

Comment: If you happened to be someone who downvoted me for this answer, could you please explain why?